# CSS Parser for android

Tags: android, css, parsing

Sorry for bad english, I'm newer developer in android studio.

In these days, i trying to search some library that works in my android application.

I researched two libraries, [CSS Parser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net/) and [ph-css](https://github.com/phax/ph-css).

These libraries i used maven repositories to deal with dependencies.

CSS Parser - I tried to copy the examples that show in CSS Parser webpage and this page (**stackoverflow.com/questions/1513587/looking-for-a-css-parser-in-java**), but some classes doesn't exist, for example: **CSSRule**.
To figured out,  I created a project in eclipse and i found the libraries that used:

```
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSRule;
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSRuleList;
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleRule;
```

With this, i search these libraries in maven repository and i found the page (**mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.4.01**)(XML-APIS). All errors was disappear, but when i compile this error appears.

```
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.

However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.

If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.

If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
```

ph-CSS - I used the same process, put in gradle the maven repository and run. Another failed, it appears this message:

```
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing com/helger/commons/CGlobal.class
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried to use this page(**stackoverflow.com/questions/37902840/got-unsupported-class-file-version-52-0-after-including-a-module-to-a-project**) in stackoverflow

Nothing happens...
And when i saw the author changelog about jdk 8, i tried to use this (**developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html?hl=en**) instead:

I removed the duplicate files and this message shows:

```
Error:Library reading phase: Type javax.annotation.Untainted from file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\CSSTest\app\build\intermediates\jill\debug\packaged\jsr305-3.0.1-dd0e9f5d0efb3025f6fde4238fd4a5c268f62a63.jar' has already been imported from file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\CSSTest\app\build\intermediates\jill\debug\packaged\annotations-3.0.1u2-2b84c751906484cab0381cba276af74c2923d73b.jar', type 'javax.annotation.Untainted' (see property 'jack.import.type.policy' for type collision policy)
com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Library reading phase: Type javax.annotation.Untainted from file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\CSSTest\app\build\intermediates\jill\debug\packaged\jsr305-3.0.1-dd0e9f5d0efb3025f6fde4238fd4a5c268f62a63.jar' has already been imported from file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\CSSTest\app\build\intermediates\jill\debug\packaged\annotations-3.0.1u2-2b84c751906484cab0381cba276af74c2923d73b.jar', type 'javax.annotation.Untainted' (see property 'jack.import.type.policy' for type collision policy)
```

Now, i have no clue how to solve this. Any tips?

Apologies, I didn't include hyperlink, because I don't have reputation requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support all features of jdk 8 hence the unsupported-class-file-version-52-0 error you get when using the latest versions of ph-css(which is compiled with jdk 8). However, you may use version 4.1.4 which is the last one to be compiled against jdk 6/7 by adding this to your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.helger:ph-css:4.1.4'
}
```